# Activity indicator on Cordova 3.1

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

In cordova 3.1 application navigator.notification.loadingStart() and Stop() are not working for me. Error comes is that ‘loadingStart is not method in NotificationEx plugin’. I am using old plugins LoadingView.h and,NotificationEx.h and m and UIColorExpand.h and m. Can u plz help me how to do this in cordova 3.1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use pre-3.x plugins with Cordova 3.0. You will need to upgrade the plugins. If you are using the CLI you can do this just by adding the plugin - it will fetch the most recent stable version from plugins.cordova.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to use older plugins. I now use Waiting Dialog plugin to solve this problem